# algorithm that outputs the cost of electric bill including tax

Tags: python

I need some help with the following algorithm for my homework assignment, I'm not sure what i did wrong but the results are not correct, I'm not even sure if I'm using the correct operations, please forgive me, I'm still learning

```
#Exercise 6: An algorithm that gets the amount of electricity used in 
#kilowatt-hours and the cost of electricity per kilowatt-hour. Its output is 
#the total amount of the electric bill, including an 8% sales tax.

watt = input('Enter watts used\n')
hour = input('Enter Hours of usage\n')
watt = float(watt)
hour = float(hour)
kilohour = ((watt * hour) / float(1000))
kilohour = float(kilohour)
cost = input('Enter your cost of kWh in USD (Example: 0.90 for 90 cents)\n')
cost = float(cost)
basecost = float(cost / kilohour)
tax = basecost * float(0.08)
tax = float(tax)
finalbill = basecost + tax
print('Your bill:',round(finalbill,2))
```

Example

Enter watts used

200

Enter Hours of usage

24

Enter your cost of kWh in USD (Example: 0.90 for 90 cents)

0.90

Your bill: 0.2

Enter watts used

300

Enter Hours of usage

24

Enter your cost of kWh in USD (Example: 0.90 for 90 cents)

0.90

Your bill: 0.14

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). See also [ask]. To start helping with this, we'd need more specifics about the problem, like what inputs you provided, what output(s) you were expecting, and what output(s) you got instead.

Comment: What isn't correct? Show input, real and expected output as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: BTW, most of those `float()` calls are redundant, like `float(0.08)`, since `0.08` is already a `float`.

Comment: General hint: Add more "print"s to show results of intermediate calculations and think if the values make sense.

Comment: ok I added the inputs and the print result

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe you got the "per kilowatt hour" concept a bit confused.  Looks like instead of dividing the "cost per kilowatt hour" by the "kilowatt hours consumed", you should be multiplying.  E.G.

```
basecost = float(cost * kilohour)
```

When I did that, I got what looked to be a nominal bill.

```
    craig@Una:~/Python_Programs/Kilowatt$ python3 Killowatt.py 
Enter watts used 10000
Enter Hours of usage 4

Enter your cost of kWh in USD (Example: 0.90 for 90 cents)
.90
Your bill: 38.88
```

Give that a try.

Answer (score -2):

Try typecasting your variables at the same time you compute them.
For Example Change:

```
watt = input('Enter watts used\n')
watt = float(watt)

//TO

watt = float(input('Enter watts used\n'))
```

You will also want to typecast all computed values.

```
kilohour = ((watt * hour) / float(1000))
kilohour = float(kilohour)

//Should be changed to

kilohour = float((float(watt * hour) / 1000))
```

Notice that `(watt * hour)` and `((watt * hour) / 1000)` are typecasted to `float` because these values are computed.

Comment: Python comments use hashes `#`, not double-slashes `//`

Comment: Doing `watt = float(input(...))` is an improvement, yes, but it won't solve the problem. Secondly, if `watt` and `hour` are already floats, multiplying and dividing them will produce floats, so those `float()` calls are entirely redundant. Please read [answer].